# how to highlight My current menu Items in css

Tags: html, css

I am working with following menu bar in laravel. I need highlight current menu item when I click it.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li style="margin-left:20px;">
            {{--<img src="{{ Auth::user()->getAvatarUrl() }}" height="50" width="50" style="border-radius:25px;" />--}}
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> @ {{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">PREGO<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('projects.index') }}">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('collaborators.form', $project)}}">Collaborators</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Todos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
        {{--<li><a href="{{ route('auth.logout') }}">Sign Out</a></li>--}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

how can do this?

Comment: You have a `active` class, set a color for example no ? And when click on an `li` you active class apply a color

Comment: where should I apply active class?

Comment: still not a success solutions..

Comment: You don't add active class. Just you try to use Jquery toogleclass script on your script

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you style the .active class will do what you want to

```
.active{
 /*add hear what you would like to change for example*/
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one of the another way to active list. Likely

Jquery:

```
<script>
  $('.nav-sidebar').on('click','li', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

And one more thing you don't add .active class in your code. After that you have to wrap your css property like

```
<style>
 .nav-sidebar li.active{
  /*your css code here*/
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Ok this is little bit working but there are some problems. currently not highlight this three links here **<li><a href="{{ route('collaborators.form', $project)}}">Collaborators</a></li>** and **<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
        {{--<li><a href="{{ route('auth.logout') }}">Sign Out</a></li>--}}
    </ul>** how can fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You will write your code in your css file. Likely

```
.nav-sidebar li.active{
 /*your code here*/
}
```

this ia also one of the way to active your current active menu.

Comment: i mean have you wrap some script?

Comment: when I use active class like this **<li class="active"><a href="{{ route('collaborators.form', $project)}}">Collaborators</a></li>** all active class are highlighted not only highlight current clickable menu...